# Maximal Ideals of Ring of real valued continuous functions defined over [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Suppose that $R$ is the ring of real valued continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$. If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then prove that $M$ will be of following form
> $$M=\{f \in R\mid f(x)=0\}$$ for a fixed $x\in[0,1]$.

Obviously the ideal given by $M=\{f \in R\mid f(x)=0\}$ is an maximal ideal for a fixed choice of $x$ in $[0,1]$.

But starting from a random maximal ideal how can I get to that form?

Comment: or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701637/29335) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1628578/29335) and some I missed, I think. Please pay attention to the questions suggested as duplicates when you post, and please search before posting. A search for "maximal ideal continuous" sufficed for me to find all of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $J$ be a proper ideal of $C[0,1]$.

Since $1 \notin J$, it follows that each $f \in J$ has at least one zero.

Claim the elements of $J$ have a common zero.

Suppose otherwise.

For each $f \in J$, let $V_f = \{x \in [0,1]\mid f(x) \ne 0\}$.

Since each $f$ is continuous, it follows that $V_f$ is open in $[0,1]$, for all $f \in J$.

By the assumption that the elements of $J$ have no common zero, it follows that $\{V_f \mid f \in J\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$.

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there must be a finite subcover $V_{f_1},...,V_{f_n}$, say.

Let $g = f_1^2 + \cdots + f_n^2$. Then $g \in J$, but $g$ has no zeros, contradiction.

Hence the elements of $J$ have a common zero, $a$ say.

Then $J$ is a subset of the maximal ideal $M_a = \{f \in C[0,1]\mid f(a) = 0\}$.

Therefore, if $J$ is maximal, we must have $J = M_a$.

Comment: I think this problem affords a unique opportunity to make use of the "dual" definition of compactness: Say a collection $\mathcal C$ of closed sets has
 "finite intersection property" if the intersection of any finite collection of things from $\mathcal C$ is nonempty.  Then $X$ is compact iff every collection $\mathcal C$ of closed sets with the f.i.p. has nonempty intersection.  The idea should be clear: the zero sets of functions are nonempty closed sets with f.i.p. It's the same idea as above, of course, but I like to think of it this way :)